# How do i delete duplicate row data in the T1table which is already there in the existingT2table which has unique constraint and showing error as below

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, copy

> SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (STARDSDEV.PK_SJSI_SCHEDULEID) violated.

I'm Trying to copy some rows between tables this error is cmng.

Comment: Whenever a unique constraint is violated, you have two options: 1) Make sure your new record is unique (that will mostly be the correct way), 2) Delete that constraint. What is your question?

Comment: Is there any way to know the common unique id between two tables and delete it

Comment: You can't delete a single column from an entire table. Please edit your question to add clarifications instead of using comments for that. Ask a question in a way people can understand and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way out is to *merge* rows using `when no matched` clause which will skip rows whose IDs already exist in the target table.

This is the original table:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Target table already contains one of these rows (`DEPTNO` is a primary key column):

```
SQL> select * from new_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

This is something like you did - without paying attention to existing rows, Oracle raises an error:

```
SQL> insert into new_dept select * from dept;
insert into new_dept select * from dept
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.PK_NEW_DEPT) violated
```

But, if you merge them, it *works*:

```
SQL> merge into new_dept a
  2  using dept b
  3  on (a.deptno = b.deptno)
  4  when not matched then
  5    insert (deptno, dname, loc)
  6    values (b.deptno, b.dname, b.loc);

3 rows merged.

SQL> select * from new_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

---

Or, a `NOT IN` option might also work:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> insert into new_dept
  2  select * from dept b
  3  where b.deptno not in (select a.deptno from new_dept a);

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from new_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL>
```